# Dynamic PDF using iReport adds a blank page at the end of second detail band

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

I have designed a report using iReport which has 2 detail bands and one page header and footer. There is a page break between the 2 detail bands to make sure that both start from a new page.
Content of the first detail band has more data than the second detail band.

The basic output is a PDF with 2 pages along with header,footer. If the content grows the number of pages increase.

Problem:
There are some cases in which the first detail band has 2 pages of data and the second one has only one page.
In the above scenario, I should be getting 3 pages in total, but I am getting a blank page at the end of the second detail band.
If the first detail band has only one page, then second page doesn't create a blank page at the end.

I have removed all the additional bands from the report and also extra space at of each band is removed.
Some guidance of experience is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reach at finding a solution to the above problem by keeping the page break at the divider of 2 bands and double clicking the line at the end of each band  to make sure that there is no space before that line and the last element in the page which is difficult to achieve by just moving the line manually.
This gave a fantastic output of only required pages.